# "Your environment is not configured properly" with Svelte-native

Tags: javascript, ios, svelte, environment, svelte-native

I try to build a little application with svelte-native. When I installed NativeScript  I created an application and I wanted to run it with

```
ns run ios
```

and I have this problem with the environment:

[image: error]

I updated pip and Xcode, but this error persists.
I have MacBook Air with macOS Monterey version 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/environment-setup.html#macos-ios)

In my terminal this command:

```
sudo ln -s $(which python3) /usr/local/bin/python
```

next step is to install pip six

```
 python3 -m pip install six
```

Now I install ios platform:

```
tns platform add ios
```

Now all works very well:

```
ns doctor ios
```

I have this answer:

[image: all without errors]

And I can run ios

```
ns run ios
```

[image: working app]